# waitFor() & waitForEnabled() not working after locateAll

Tags: karate

I am getting below error:

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: waitForEnabled(allValueInOnusDropdown[0]).click()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (waitForEnabled) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome@151335cb failed due to: Cannot convert '(document._karate.ref1692702824695)'(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverElement) to Java type 'java.lang.String': Invalid or lossy primitive coercion.
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
* def allValueInOnusDropdown = locateAll('locator')
* waitForEnabled(allValueInOnusDropdown[0]).click()
* waitFor(allValueInOnusDropdown[0]).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

So [`waitForEnabled`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waitforenabled) is a special shortcut and you are trying to mix it into other parts of Karate in un-supported ways.

This may work, but I haven't tried it:

```
* allValueInOnusDropdown[0].waitUntil('!_.disabled').click()
```

Else, you may need to do this in more steps, you are most welcome to contribute code to Karate to make it better.

Comment: Where can i find source code of Karate AND a starting video/tutorial to understand it so that i may hopefully contribute in future. Please suggest @PeterSmith

Comment: @Yash you can start here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide